# SSRS 2008 subscriptions have incorrect data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have written, and rewritten, a hospital census query for which I would like to create a daily Windows File Share subscription. The query seems fine; it runs properly in SSMS, BIDS, and on the SSRS Report Server itself. However, when I create any kind of subscription, sometimes the report will have old and incorrect data on it. There is no real pattern to when the report generates incorrectly, as far as I can tell, but the data that gets sent incorrectly is consistently the same, and is from back in January. I had initially written the query on a test server with the same data, just a little bit older, and had changed the dates that it would run for. I also had to re-deploy the report a few times after making changes. I had initially deployed it from the test system directly to the live server, so I tried completely redoing it in the live system, in addition to making some changes improve performance, but I am still getting the same incorrect data.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated at this point, because I am at a loss and I am really just getting started with SQL.
Thank you for any assistance.

**Edits:** adding the queries that are returning the inconsistent data; removing my comments that have poorly-formatted code.
Also, to be a bit more specific about the issue: The subscription sometimes sends the census data for the day before as expected, and sometimes it sends the census data from January 15, and this only happens in the subscription.

Query 1:

```
SELECT  
V.Name AS PatientName  
,V.AccountNumber AS AccountNumber  
,V.FinancialClassName AS FinancialClass  
,V.ServiceDateTime  
,P.EmergencyID AS Provider  
,X.ErDateTime AS Discharge  
,X.ErDispositionID AS Disposition  
FROM dbo.AdmVisits AS V  

INNER JOIN dbo.AdmProviders AS P  
ON P.VisitID=V.VisitID  

INNER JOIN dbo.AdmDischarge AS X  
ON V.VisitID=X.VisitID  

WHERE CAST(V.ServiceDateTime AS DATE)=CAST(DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE)  
    OR CAST(X.ErDateTime AS DATE)=CAST(DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE)  
ORDER BY V.Name
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
V.Name
,V.AccountNumber
,V.FinancialClassName
,V.InpatientServiceID
,V.RoomID
,D.AdmitDateTime
,P.AdmitID
,P.AttendID
,X.DischargeDateTime
,X.DispositionName

FROM dbo.AdmVisits AS V

INNER JOIN dbo.AdmittingData AS D
ON V.VisitID=D.VisitID

INNER JOIN dbo.AdmProviders AS P
ON P.VisitID=D.VisitID

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AdmDischarge AS X
ON V.VisitID=X.VisitID

WHERE V.InpatientOrOutpatient='I'
    AND NOT V.InpatientServiceID='INP LTC'
    AND (CAST(D.AdmitDateTime AS DATE)<CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE))
    AND (V.Status='ADM IN' OR  CAST(X.DischargeDateTime AS DATE)=CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE))
ORDER BY V.Name
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT 
V.Name
,V.AccountNumber
,V.FinancialClassName
,V.InpatientServiceID
,V.RoomID
,D.AdmitDateTime
,P.AdmitID
,P.AttendID
,X.DischargeDateTime
,X.DispositionName
,CASE   
    WHEN V.LoaStatus IN('F','L') THEN CAST(V.LoaEffectiveDateTime AS varchar)
    Else 'No'
    END AS 'LeaveOfAbsence'

FROM dbo.AdmVisits AS V

INNER JOIN dbo.AdmittingData AS D
ON V.VisitID=D.VisitID

INNER JOIN dbo.AdmProviders AS P
ON P.VisitID=D.VisitID

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AdmDischarge AS X
ON V.VisitID=X.VisitID

WHERE V.InpatientServiceID='INP LTC'
    AND (CAST(D.AdmitDateTime AS DATE)<CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE))
    AND (V.Status='ADM IN' OR  CAST(X.DischargeDateTime AS DATE)=CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE))

ORDER BY V.Name
```

Comment: Please include more information about your problem. The juicy parts like queries and data :)

Comment: Hi MyGGaN, 
I can't really post the data in a way that would be useful, but I will post my queries. I kind of misspoke above; when I rewrote that first query, I wrote three separate queries in the hopes that maybe it was a caching issue or something like that.

Comment: @MyGGaN - Really sorry about the formatting. I did put two spaces at the end of each line.  
At any rate, these same queries are yielding different results on the subscription that I have running right now. Sometimes the report will contain yesterday's census as they ought to, and sometimes it will contain the census for January 15.

Comment: please edit your question with those queries. As you said, they don't look to nice in the comments.

Comment: @MyGGaN - Added the queries to the question. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue was the data source's connection string to the server. I was using 'localhost' instead of the server's actual name, and since the test and live servers are basically clones of one another, I think it wasn't consistently connecting to the right server. Not sure how exactly that works, but the report is working now.